# How do I git pull without overwriting a single file

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to git.  I use

```
git push origin master
```

to push my app, and

```
git pull origin master
```

to pull it down.  I do not want to overwrite one single file: db/development.sqlite3, because it has all of the data that has been inputted by users on my live app.  However, when I push changes from my developing computer, then go to pull them to the live server, I get an error saying that I cannot pull changes because that file is different now and would be overwritten by the merge.  It says please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.  But I just want git to not pull and overwrite that file at all.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't have a copy of that file under version control.

Comment: how do i remove it from being under version control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop tracking the file in your repo.

```
git rm --cached db/development.sqlite3
```

This will remove it from your repo but retain the current state of the file.  Then you should create a `.gitignore` file that has this file listed in it.

Comment: when I create the .gitignore file, which machine do I put it on.  The server? or the workstation?

Comment: You commit it to the repo.

Comment: So I would add the db/development.sqlite3 file to .gitignore, then git add and git commit that file, and from then on, it will ignore that file anytime I push or pull from my repo?

Comment: Once it is no longer being tracked in your repo also.  The .gitignore file will prevent the file from showing up in the untracked files also so that you don't accidentally add and commit in the future.

Comment: Stopping tracking *locally* (via the `git rm --cached db/development.sqlite3` above) is definitely a good idea, but the .gitignore issue requires some thought.  It's not clear to me that it *should* be added to a committed `.gitignore`, at least not without consulting with other team members - the production environment may be relying on others checking in (and updating) a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a branch and commit the changes of that file to it. Then do a `git pull origin master`. You can merge the branch later on..